# Battery power for electric door motor

Tags: battery-charging

I am adding a motor to my door to operate a latch.  The motor needs 12v DC and a third 12v pulse to trigger it to open.  The power supply will only be available while the door is closed (it is a pivot door with no hinges).

The attached diagram shows the wiring..  the question is how to keep power to reset the motor when the door is open.  The motor beeps when tiggered, then engages for 2 seconds pulling in the latches so you can open the door, then it should release the latches.

I was planning on fitting a 12v battery into the door so that the motor still has power.  Ideally the battery could be charged whilst the door is closed.  I just don't know how that would work.

1. Do I need to run a separate charging circuit to to door for the battery or could I make use of the 12v circuit.
2. Can I just plug the battery inline with the 12v circuit.  I would leave the pulse out because this only triggers when the door is shut.

[image]

Comment: Please stop using the "12v" tag on your questions -- it is deprecated, as indicated in its wiki.